# Commandbutton is not passing object

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to create Dilogue box containing a record of datatable. I am using latest version of primfaces implementation.

Following is the XHTML code,

```
 <h:form prependId="false" id ="dilogueForm" > 
                    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"  
                              showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">  
                        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

                            <h:outputText value="Project:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{saveData.selectedProject.prjName}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Description:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{saveData.selectedProject.prjDesc}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Client:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{saveData.selectedProject.prjClientname}" />  

                            <h:outputText value="Effort:" />  
                            <h:outputText value="#{saveData.selectedProject.prjEffort}" />  

                            <p:column headerText="Color">  
                                <h:commandButton value ="Save" actionListener="#{saveData.selectProjectFromDialog(selectedProject)}" />  
                            </p:column> 
                        </h:panelGrid>  
                    </p:dialog>  
   </h:form>
```

Here:

Selected project is populated from following datatable definition:

```
<p:dataTable id="ProjectDataTable" var="p" value="#{saveData.projectList}"  
                                     selection="#{saveData.selectedProject}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{p.prjId}">
```

On the managed bean,

```
public void selectProjectFromDialog(Project project) {  
     System.out.println("Project"+project.toString());
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(project);  
}
```

Here i am getting project value as null.

Could you please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:commandButton value ="Save" actionListener="#{saveData.selectProjectFromDialog(selectedProject)}" />
```

should be

```
<h:commandButton value ="Save" actionListener="#{saveData.selectProjectFromDialog(saveData.selectedProject)}" />
```

Comment: I have tried this but have not worked. Still I am getting SelectedProject value as null.

Comment: Do you see values of your output texts in the dialog pop-up? If yes, what is the scope of your bean ? Also, be aware of nested forms. Where is the form which wraps your dialog pop-up ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<p:commandButton value ="Save" process="@this, display" partialSubmit="true" ajax="true" action="#{saveData.selectProjectFromDialog(saveData.selectedProject)}" />
```